# mysql stored procedure syntax error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Ok, this is only the second stored procedure I've written.  I think you'll get the idea, I'm trying to close a credit line, and all invoices, charges, notes, etc with it.  But I get a syntax error.
The goal is to CALL close_account_proc(398985994)

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
    PROCEDURE `cc`.`close_account_proc`(cid INT)
    @uid_usr := uid_usr FROM credit_acc WHERE type_acc = 'init' AND credit_used_acc = cid;
    UPDATE credit_acc SET status_acc = 'closed', void_date_acc = NOW() WHERE credit_used_acc = cid;
    UPDATE payment_acc SET status_acc = 'voided', void_date_acc = NOW()  WHERE creditid_acc = cid;
    UPDATE sbal_sbl SET status_sbl = 'voided', void_date_sbl = NOW()  WHERE credit_used_acc = cid;
    INSERT INTO notes_not SET uid_usr = @uid_usr, initials_not = 'SYS',status_not = 'complete', date_not = NOW(), text_not = 'Closed credit line '.cid;
    UPDATE invoices_inv SET status_inv = 'voided', void_date_inv = NOW()  WHERE credit_used_acc = cid;
    BEGIN
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

So, anway, I get this error:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@uid_usr := uid_usr from credit_acc where type_acc = 'init' and credit_used_acc ' at line 5.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `cc`.`close_account_proc`(cid INT)
BEGIN
    /* Check that it's what you wanted */
    SELECT  uid_usr
    INTO    @uid_usr
    FROM    credit_acc
    WHERE   type_acc = 'init'
            AND credit_used_acc = cid;

    UPDATE credit_acc SET status_acc = 'closed', void_date_acc = NOW() WHERE credit_used_acc = cid;
    UPDATE payment_acc SET status_acc = 'voided', void_date_acc = NOW()  WHERE creditid_acc = cid;
    UPDATE sbal_sbl SET status_sbl = 'voided', void_date_sbl = NOW()  WHERE credit_used_acc = cid;

    /* Check that it's what you wanted */

    INSERT
    INTO    notes_not (uid_usr, initials_not, status_not, date_not, text_not)
    VALUES  (@uid_usr, 'SYS', 'complete', NOW(), CONCAT('Closed credit line ', cid));

    UPDATE invoices_inv SET status_inv = 'voided', void_date_inv = NOW()  WHERE credit_used_acc = cid;
END
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, im no expert at stored procedures, but isn't it.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `cc`.`close_account_proc`(cid INT)
    BEGIN
        // your stuff
    END$$
```

Comment: Yes, you're correct, but there was a lot more wrong with it :)