# Creating procedure on MySQL hosted on iPage

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mysql stored procedure syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753331/mysql-stored-procedure-syntax-error)

Why can't I create a procedure on my iPage Hosting Service.

When I try to create a procedure without any commands inside, everything goes well. But, even if I try a very simple procedure like the one bellow, I always get an error:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE \`LOGAR_USUARIO\` ()
BEGIN
   SELECT * FROM TB_USUARIO;
END;
```

Would you help me to understand what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely error is a delimiter error:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE `LOGAR_USUARIO` ()
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM TB_USUARIO;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

The syntax should be fine now. But your procedure does nothing useful: it selects all records in table TB_USUARIO, and nothing else. The selected records are not used for anything.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. This is just an example (even this simple procedure is not working). I've done the way you described and I am getting the following message:ERROR: String de pontuação desconhecida @ 11
STR: //
SQL: DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE `LOGAR_USUARIO` ()
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM TB_USUARIO;

Comment: I just tested my query in my own MySQL database, it runs fine and does not cause any punctuation error. You need to explain what you are doing and when the punctuation error is happening.

Comment: I've done the same here. The procedure runs well on my own MySQL database but not on iPage's. I really don't know what to try. I thought about MySQL version, but I don't think it would be since the procedure is very, very simple. I am trying to run this procedure on phpAdmin, directly on website. Any other suggestions?